# can't delete a file starting with a '-'

Tags: linux, command-line

i have a file is name

> -ksh.l.15092015.log

to delete this file i do this:

```
rm -rf -ksh.l.15092015.log
```

but i have this error:

> rm: Not a recognized flag: k
>
> Usage: rm [-firRe] [--] File...

i have do this:

```
rm -rf *ksh*
```

but i have the same errors, why ?

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute this:

```
rm -rf ./-ksh.l.15092015.log
```

Comment: it's work fine, thx !

Answer (score 5):

This is a nice question, and from what I remember some sysadmin interviews make use of it.

You have multiple ways of doing this:

- Remove using relative or absolute path. As SHW has said in his answer:

  ```
  rm -rf ./-ksh.l.15092015.log
  ```

  or

  ```
  rm -rf /full/path/-ksh.l.15092015.log
  ```
- Remove by disabling the interpretation of dash (**-**) for **rm**

  ```
  rm -- -ksh.l.15092015.log
  ```
- And the more convoluted way :), using the inode:

  ```
  ls -li | grep ksh.l.15092015.log

  5383819 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 sep 15 13:17 -ksh.l.15092015.log

  find . -inum 5383819 -delete
  ```

You could also use **mc** and **vim**, but these are the **"shell"** ways that I know.

Comment: "disabling the the shell interpretation of dash" — incorrect. The shell does not interpret that dash, it's the `rm` command that does it.